# can I time tasks in python without stopping other tasks

Tags: python, flask

I request from the football-data.org api and i time it so i have unlimited requests but when i put this code in the main file which is the body of my website the time.sleep() stops other essential functions from executing
is there a way i can run these simultaneously without stopping the essential functions

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, flash, request, url_for
from pymongo import MongoClient
import http.client
import json
import time
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/footballScoreDB")
db = cluster["footballScorePy"]
collection = db["footballScore"]

        
def get_matches(league):

    status = ["FINISHED", "LIVE", "SCHEDULED"]

    x = 0

    while(x < 3):
        

        uri = "https://api.football-data.org/v4/competitions/" + league + "/matches?status=" + status[x]
        headers = { 'X-Auth-Token': 'api key' }

        response = requests.get(uri, headers=headers)   
        


        matches = response.json()["matches"]

        length = response.json()["resultSet"]["count"]
        i=0


        collection.delete_many({"league": league , "status": status[x]})

        while(i != length): 
        
            awayTeam = matches[i]["awayTeam"]["name"]   
            homeTeam = matches[i]["homeTeam"]["name"]
            homeTeamCrest = matches[i]["homeTeam"]["crest"]
            awayTeamCrest = matches[i]["awayTeam"]["crest"]

            date = matches[i]["utcDate"]
            winner = matches[i]["score"]["winner"]

            awayScore = matches[i]["score"]["fullTime"]["away"]
            awayHalfTimeScore = matches[i]["score"]["halfTime"]["away"]

            homeScore = matches[i]["score"]["fullTime"]["home"]
            homeHalfTimeScore = matches[i]["score"]["halfTime"]["home"]
    

            if status == "FINISHED":

                post = {
                    "homeTeam": homeTeam,
                    "awayTeam": awayTeam,
                    "date": date,
                    "homeScore": homeScore,
                    "awayScore": awayScore,
                    "homeHalfTimeScore": homeHalfTimeScore,
                    "awayHalfTimeScore": awayHalfTimeScore,
                    "winner": winner,
                    "status": status[x],
                    "league": league,
                    "awayTeamCrest": awayTeamCrest,
                    "homeTeamCrest": homeTeamCrest
                }

            elif status == "LIVE":  

                    post = {
                        "homeTeam": homeTeam,
                        "awayTeam": awayTeam,
                        "date": "LIVE",
                        "homeScore": homeScore,
                        "awayScore": awayScore,
                        "homeHalfTimeScore": 0,
                        "awayHalfTimeScore": 0,
                        "winner": 0,
                        "status": status[x],
                        "league": league,
                        "awayTeamCrest": awayTeamCrest,
                        "homeTeamCrest": homeTeamCrest
                    }

            else :

                    post = {
                        "homeTeam": homeTeam,
                        "awayTeam": awayTeam,
                        "date": date,
                        "homeScore": 0,
                        "awayScore": 0,
                        "homeHalfTimeScore": 0,
                        "awayHalfTimeScore": 0,
                        "winner": 0,
                        "status": status[x],
                        "league": league,
                        "awayTeamCrest": awayTeamCrest,
                        "homeTeamCrest": homeTeamCrest
                    }
                    
            if collection.find_one(post) == False :
                collection.insert_one(post)
                
            

            i+=1

        x+=1   


@app.route("/")
def home():

    return "testing"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port="4000")
    while True:
        get_matches("PL")
        get_matches("SA")
        get_matches("DED")
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: You can run that request fn in a separate thread (spawn some threads and call `get_matches` fns in those) , and have Flask's server running on the main one. From here you can get that API requesting thread to just store it's findings in the MongoDB, and use that in your Flask endpoints... There might be some issue like: *Say If I call an endpoint when the requesting isn't done yet*, obviously you can just check mongo to see if the data is there. I recommend this recourse: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/flask-python-mongodb/

Comment: thanks so much it works now can you post this as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run that request fn in a separate thread (spawn some threads and call `get_matches` fns in those) , and have Flask's server running on the main one. From here you can get that API requesting thread to just store it's findings in the MongoDB, and use that in your Flask endpoints... There might be some issue like: Say If I call an endpoint when the requesting isn't done yet, obviously you can just check mongo to see if the data is there. I recommend this recourse: [Flask Python MongoDB](https://mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/flask-python-mongodb)